# navbar is not showing the nav links after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this navigation bar, it works fine when i am in the top of my web page. whenever i scroll down it dose scroll but i  have to got to the top to see the nav links. one more thing: in my gallery page navbar is not covering the page content(the images). Same problem is occurring in my home page. I can't even use the nav links. Please Help me.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 46%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    font-weight: lighter;
} */
/* 
body{
    background: #101010;
} */
.toggle-btn {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1.4em;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 40px;
    height: 12px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

span.one {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(105, 48, 48);
    margin-right: 60px;
}

span.two {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(105, 48, 48);
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.menu {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background:#000000;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: -200%;
}

.data {
    padding: 8em 0 0 2em;
    text-align: left;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li:first-child {
    color: grey;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 24px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 42px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cccccc;
    font-family: Poppins;
}


**HTML**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">


 <!-- navigation animation -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',  filename='dist/css/nav.css') }}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>


 <!-- gallery css -->


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css"/>
 <!-- google fonts -->

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400|Roboto+Mono:300i,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- gsap -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

 <!-- jquery -->

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

 <!-- parllax javascript -->
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-parallax-js@5.2.0/dist/simpleParallax.min.js"></script>

 <!-- bootstrap CDN -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/css/custom.css') }}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/sal.js/dist/sal.css') }}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/css/grid-gallery.css') }}">
 <!-- font awesome -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a766f28a10.js"></script>
 <title>AW Zone / {{title}}</title>
 <style>
  body {
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- new navigation is here -->
 <div class="toggle-btn">
  <span class="one"></span>
  <span class="two"></span>
   </div>

   <div class="menu">
  <div class="data">
    <ul>
      <li>Navigation</li>
      <li ><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Home</a></li>
      <li ><a href="{{ url_for('gallery') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}" style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
 <!-- navbar ends here -->
  
<div class="container text-center" data-sal="slide-up" data-sal-delay="1500" data-sal-easing="ease-out-bouce" data-sal-duration="1200">
    <h2 style="font-family: poppins, sens-serif;font-size: 3em;padding-top: 60px;">Gallery</h2>
</div>

<section class="gallery-block grid-gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading">
            <h4 id="heading" data-sal="slide-up" data-sal-delay="1200" data-sal-easing="ease-out-bouce" data-sal-duration="1200">Wedding</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item">
                <a class="lightbox" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                    <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" data-sal="slide-up" data-sal-delay="1200" data-sal-easing="ease-out-bouce" data-sal-duration="1200">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item">
                <a class="lightbox" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                    <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item">
                <a class="lightbox" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                    <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item">
                <a class="lightbox" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                    <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item">
                <a class="lightbox" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                    <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item">
                <a class="lightbox" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                    <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/256737/pexels-photo-256737.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                </a>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- bootstrap 4 JAVASCRIPT  -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- greensock -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.1.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{  url_for('static', filename='node_modules/sal.js/dist/sal.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var t1 = new TimelineMax({paused: true});

    t1.to(".one", 0.8, {
         y: 6,
         rotation: 45,
         opacity:1,
         ease: Expo.easeInOut
    });
    t1.to(".two", 0.8, {
         y: -6,
         opacity: 1,
         rotation: -45,
         ease: Expo.easeInOut,
         delay: -0.8
    });

    t1.to(".menu", 2, {
         top: "0%",
         ease: Expo.easeInOut,
         delay: -2
    });

    t1.staggerFrom(".menu ul li", 2, {x: -200, opacity: 0, ease:Expo.easeOut}, 0.3);

    t1.reverse();
    $(document).on("click", ".toggle-btn", function() {
         t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
    });
    /*$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
         t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
    });*/

 </script>
 <!-- gallery effects -->

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>


 <!-- script for gallery animation -->
 <script>
  baguetteBox.run('.grid-gallery', { animation: 'slideIn'});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to use position: sticky or position: fixed with your menu class

Comment: @iamvatsalay Please provide some screenshots, what is your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `.menu` to `position: fixed;`. You also need `z-index: 1;` to make sure it overlays the other content.

```
.menu {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000000;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: -200%;
}
```